# How should I use encapsulated variable in outter function in Python without global?

Tags: python, global, encapsulation

I am trying to write two functions: `function_1` is executed inside `function_2`, however it is using the object `var` instanced inside `function_2`. Issue is that `var` is encapsulated inside `function_2` and is not reachable for `function_1`. How can I work that out not using the `global` variable? New instance `var` must be created with every iteration of the while loop.

```
def function_1():
    var.method()

def function_2():
    while True:
        var = Object()
        function_1()
```

Comment: Once you have created `var` inside `function_2()`, you can pass it as a parameter to `function_1()`

Comment: As simple as useful!!! Many thanks ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function parameter:

```py
def function_1(parameter):
    parameter.method()

def function_2():
    while True:
        var = Object()
        function_1(var)
```